# What does the following code taken from the Emscripten project mean?

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I was reading the [following code](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/e0c3ce6d2b3f121abab481e6e79a1a60e2fcd18b/system/include/emscripten/em_math.h#L33) from the Emscripten project:

```c
// The following operations have very fast WebAssembly opcodes. Therefore they are not
// exposed as individual functions:

// Math.abs(x) -> f32.abs and f64.abs. (use fabsf() and fabs() from math.h)
// Math.ceil -> f32.ceil and f64.ceil (ceil() and ceilf() in math.h)
// Math.clz32(x) -> i32.clz and i64.clz (call __builtin_clz() and __builtin_clzll())
// Math.floor -> f32.floor and f64.floor (floor() and floorf() in math.h)
// Math.fround -> f64.promote_f32(f32.demote_f64()) (call double d = (double)(float)someDouble;)
// Math.imul(x, y) -> i32.mul and i64.mul (directly multiply two signed integers)
// Math.min -> f32.min and f64.min (fminf() and fmin() in math.h)
// Math.max -> f32.max and f64.max (fmaxf() and fmax() in math.h)
// Math.trunc -> f32.trunc and f64.trunc (truncf() and trunc() in math.h)
```

Can anyone please explain what exactly is meant by the statement *"very fast WebAssembly opcodes"*.

I have a slight understanding of WebAssembly also about opcodes. However, I can't understand how come, for example, `Math.floor()` produces a fast opcode when it internally relies on the `floor()` function in C, from the `math.h` library.

The confusion starts off when I read the code that follows in the given link. `Math.round()` from JavaScript isn't considered to produce a "fast WebAssembly opcode", yet it also uses a C function, in particular `round()` again from `math.h`.

How is `round()` in C any different from `floor()` in C, and how that does difference equate to one call being able to produce a quicker opcode.

Comment: The `floor()` goes *down* to the next integer value, `ceil()` goes *up* to the next, and `round()` goes to the nearest. The `floor()` and `ceil()` might be marginally quicker than `round()` because they have no decision to make about the direction. It's irrelevant though, because only one of those three will be the one that you need.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it means that those functions aren't exposed because they would never get called, because compiled code would use [the equivalent opcodes](https://pengowray.github.io/wasm-ops/) instead of the opcodes that would perform a function call. But I'm neither an Emscripten nor WebAssembly expert.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that makes sense but still a bit more insight would be helpful :)